# Search posts in Facebook group by date range

Tags: facebook, date, range, group

At first sorry for my English it is not so good.
My question is: is there a method to search posts in a Facebook group using a date range filter without tapping any text or keyword in the search bar.
For example a group named: "Car Spotting" (Can I find all the posts that has been posted in it in the date range of 01/05/2020 to 05/06/2020.
Thank you all!

Couldn't find a date filter of day/month/year search in a Facebook group.